# VBA : Put the value of three ComboBox in one Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to create a formular, and I have a problem.
I want to put the value of ComboBox1(Days), ComboBox2(Mounths) and ComboBox3(Years) in one Excel cell (Cell G)

This is a part of my script :

```
f MsgBox("Confirmez-vous l’insertion de ce nouveau contact ?", vbYesNo, "Demande de confirmation d’ajout") = vbYes Then

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1 'Pour placer le nouvel enregistrement à la première ligne de tableau non vide

    MsgBox i

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("A" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("B" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("C" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("D" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox4.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("E" & i).Value = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("F" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox4.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("H" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("I" & i).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox7.Value

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("E" & i).NumberFormat = "00 00 00 00 00"

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("H" & i).NumberFormat = "00"

    Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy"



End If 
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Here's how you set the column G value: `Sheets("Reservations").Range("G" & i).Value = DateSerial(UserForm1.ComboBox3.Value, UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value, UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value)` and then it will be formatted correctly based on your NumberFormat later in your code.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it's working !!

Comment: @tigeravatar Do you have any idea to do the same think, but this time for time time o'clock.